# MSTest Shows Partial Code Coverage on Compound Boolean Expressions

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, code-coverage

From Microsoft's documentation, partially covered code is *"...where some of the code blocks within the line were not executed."* I'm pretty stumped on this one (simplified for brevity):

Given this method:

```
public List<string> CodeUnderTest()
{
    var collection = new List<string> { "test1", "test2", "test3" };
    return collection.Where(x => x.StartsWith("t") && x == "test2").ToList();
}
```

And this test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    var result = new Class1().CodeUnderTest();
    CollectionAssert.Contains(result, "test2");
}
```

Code coverage results shows that the expression `x.StartsWith("t") && x == "test2` is only partially covered. I'm not sure how that's possible unless the compiler or CLR has some sort of eager condition matching stuff, but maybe I just need to have it explained.

Comment: Of note, the same is true of using `||` with multiple boolean conditions.

Comment: it makes sense with `||` of course, but it doesn't make sense with `&&` -- if the `&&` statement evaluates to true, how could it possibly skip any of the conditions? -- I'm running into this issue now and it's crazy.  Makes zero sense.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The conditional-AND operator (&&) performs a logical-AND of its bool operands, but only evaluates its second operand if necessary.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk(v=vs.100).aspx

so you would expect both sides to be covered

perhaps what it is complaining about is that you haven't tested the -ve paths i.e. if your collection is

```
var collection = new List<string> { "test1", "test2", "test3", "not_this_one" };
```

this way you test the `x.StartsWith("t")` being T/F because currently only the T path is being tested for that condition.

Comment: So after some digging, when using `&&` it seems that it doesn't consider code fully covered unless, given: `A && B`, the code tests `{A=true,B=false}` (false), `{A=false,B=not evaluated}` (false), and `{A=true,B=true}` (true). But only when compounded. Given `A` or `B` individually, it doesn't matter if they're true or false.

Comment: @lukiffer, that is correct. Visual Studio's coverage tool works via [basic block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_block) analysis. Basically, there's a probe at the start of each basic block to record if it gets executed during the test. In the case of statements such as these, multiple basic blocks map to the same line. If any of the basic blocks don't execute (such as by conditional evaluation short-circuiting, as you've noticed), then the line will show as partially covered. Source: I was the developer of the coverage tools up to VS2012.

Comment: But, if A is true, and B is true -- then both blocks of code that *I* wrote got executed -- (it had to evaluate both of them, yes?) -- but you're saying I have to test all combinations of such, because of compiler generated blocks? -- Seems kind of nuts that I should have to test the compiler generated code. :-/

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 you don't have to but you would if you are looking for full branch coverage and not just statement coverage

Comment: So how is this partially covered: `if (x.Collection != null && x.Collection.Count != 0) { }` and this fully covered: `if (x.Collection != null) if (x.Collection.Count != 0) { }` with the same test set.