# Visual Studio 2012 code coverage partially touched area

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, code-coverage

I have a problem with Visual Studio 2012 unit testing, more precisely - with code coverage.
Here is a target code:

```
var someDeals = allDeals
            .Where(i => i.Number != null && !i.Number.StartsWith(SomeString))
            .Select(i => new DealInfoDto
            {
                CurrentDebtAmount = i.CurrentDebtAmount,
                Date = i.Date,
                NextMonthlyPaymentDate = i.NextMonthlyPaymentDate,
                Number = i.Number,
                AccountNumber = i.AccountNumber,
            })
            .ToArray();
```

When I run analyze code coverage it shows me that lambda expression in second line (`i.Number != null && !i.Number.StartsWith(SomeString)`) is partially touched area and I can't get 100% coverage. But I'm sure that this expression is evaluated (expression inside SELECT is OK, so expression inside WHERE is true and that's mean that both parts of && statement were touched, also I've checked data and I'm sure that `i.Number != null` and `!i.Number.StartsWith(SomeString)`.

Why this block is not covered?

P.S. I splitted `Where` into two expressions and everything became OK. But it looks smth ugly and would be better just one `Where`:

```
allDeals
    .Where(i => i.Number != null)
    .Where(i => !i.Number.StartsWith(CardAccountIdentifier))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question looks very similar to [MSTest Shows Partial Code Coverage on Compound Boolean Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947507/mstest-shows-partial-code-coverage-on-compound-boolean-expressions).

What I suspect is happening is that you are not testing the early fail path when `i.Number` is `null`.

If you remember [&&](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) will only evaluate the second expression if the first was true. In your case I suspect (as you haven't mentioned how or what your tests are) that you do not have a test or scenario where there is an entry in your `allDeals` collection where `i.Number` is `null`.